# solve_bvp value error for coupled second order ode

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I am new on Python and trying to solve a BVP problem, basing myself on the code from `scipy.integrate.solve_ode` page. Here is what I did:

```
mu=0
eta =1
Vz = 1

def dU_dx(U,x):
    return np.vstack((U[1], (((+Vz-mu)*U[0])/eta -U[1]*(1/x))))
def dV_dx(V,x):
    return np.vstack((V[1], ((-Vz-mu)*V[0] -V[1]*(1/x)-V[1]*(1/x**2))/eta))

#Implement evaluation of the boundary condition residuals:

def bc1(ya1,yb1): #for U

    return np.array([ya1[0]-1,yb1[0]])

def bc2(ya2,yb2): #for V

    return np.array([ya2[0], yb2[0]])

#Define the initial mesh with 5 nodes:

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5) 

#This problem is known to have two solutions. To obtain both of them, we use two different initial guesses for y. We denote them by subscripts a and b.

y_a = np.full((2,x.size), 0.0001) # avoiding divide by zero

y_b = np.full((2,x.size), 0.0001)

y_a[0] = 1

#Now we are ready to run the solver.

from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

res_a = solve_bvp(dU_dx, bc1, x, y_a, verbose=2)

#res_b = solve_bvp(dV_dx, bc1, x, y_b)

#Plot

x_plot = np.linspace(10**-6, 50, 100)

y_plot_a = res_a.sol(x_plot)[0]
#y_plot_b = res_b.sol(x_plot)[0]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot_a, label='y_a')
#plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot_b, label='y_b')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

This gives me the error

> "ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 5".

As far as I understand, they should match, since I've used `x.size` to construct `y_a` and `y_b`.
Thanks.

Comment: sorry I thought I had an idea what went wrong but I was wrong - I deleted the answer as it was not helpful

Comment: @pygri, okay, thanks for trying :)

Comment: so I suspect a problem in the dU_dx function - it should be able to accept x and y_a as input, right? and yet if I call dU_dx(x,y_a) I get that error - so you should try to fix that function such that it runs with those inputs.

Comment: maybe you just need to switch U and x in dU_dx ?

Comment: ooh, it worked! Not the plot I wanted, but at least something appeared haha. Thank you very much! I'll keep looking.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please include a bit more of the traceback to see exactly where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks! I 'll post another one, since I have a completely different problem now.